# get list of files which are merged as part of last run in git

Tags: git, merge, branch, release

Get list of files which are merged as part of last run in git

I have dev_branch & master. Developer(s) commits changes to dev_branch.

As part of simple release workflow, all channges made from dev_branch is merged to master.

As part of incremental deployment needed, would like to know what set of files has been merged since last image on master.

Few things..

A. `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`  -- Gives me only one of changeList but not all changeList changes merged to master

B. `git diff --name-only master dev_branch` - gets me what I need but I cannot run this once merge is complete.

Comment: Would like to avoid something like `git checkout -` or `git checkout @{-1}`& then proceeding on computing if there is straight way of retrieving list of all merged files to master from dev_branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you report suggest that you are doing "fast-forward" merges.  In workflows where one side of the merge has no changes, this is the default behavior.

When you do a fast-forward merge, certain knowledge is lost - such as the identify of the "previous master commit".

(I should clarify - The identify of the previous master commit should still exist in the reflog of the repo where the merge occurred.  Right after the merge, you could - *in the same repo* - say

```
git diff master master@{1}
```

to get what you're after.  But reflogs are not shared among repos - i.e. push and fetch don't propagate them.  And they aren't permanent.  And they change whenever refs move.  They're a good tool for recovering from mistakes, but I wouldn't make them a part of your "happy path" workflow.)

One of the key advantages of workflows like "check in to dev, periodically merge to master" is that you *keep* that knowledge of "what was the previous master commit".  You keep that knowledge by preserving the branch topology, and you do that by using the `--no-ff` option in your merge command

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff dev_branch
```

Now instead of moving the `master` ref to the existing commit at the `dev_branch` tip, git will create a new "merge commit" that joins the two histories.  The resulting content (`TREE` object) is the same.

Some people will complain about this, because they believe merge commits are "ugly" and that linearized histories are more aesthetically pleasing.  If you're entrenched in that camp, you'll have to use a clumsier solution - and I'll offer some.

But if you want to get the benefit of separating your `dev` branch from your `maser` branch, it's as simple as using true merges (`--no-ff`) and then

```
git diff master^ master
```

will start showing you what you want.

As for the clumsier solutions: Well, if you do stick with fast-forward merges, then what you need is to preserve knowledge of the previous master branch.  So you could use tags.

```
git checkout master
git tag -f old_master
git merge dev_branch
git diff old_master master
```

The above procedure is not terrible, but it does make moving a tag part of your routine.  That's not the best thing, so instead you could use a branch

```
# 1st time
git checkout master
git branch old_master
git merge dev_branch
git diff old_master master

# subsequent times
git checkout old_master
git merge --ff-only master
git checkout master
git merge dev_branch
git diff old_master master
```

(Note that I used `--ff-only` when advancing `old_master`; this shouldn't matter, because if you follow this workflow the merge will always default to a fast-forward anyway; using the flag would simply cause the process to halt with an error if those expectations weren't met.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume `master` is 123abc and `dev` is 321cba.

Your second example is equivalent to `git diff 123abc 321cba` before the merge.

After the merge, `master` is now 456def.

But you can still use `git diff 123abc 321cba` after the merge. The branch names point to new hashes but the old hashes stick around forever.

`git log` will give you the hash names if you forgot them, and tagging can be used to simplify.

Comment: +1, agree on approach. But I would like to compute this dynamically without knowledge of hash on branch & master..
I can look to compute hashe(s) with some scripting around, but like to know on more options which could be available with git VCS